# XSLT template in another file

Tags: templates, xslt

Can I call another xslt template file that is reusable for/by other XSLT files. More like a common file/Helper xslt.( i am specifically using templates)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and links to the normative W3C Specification.

Answer (score 2):

This is not XSLT 2.0 - specific question.

**Both in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 you can use the directives:**

**[`<xsl:import>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#import)**

**and**

**[`<xsl:include>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#include)**